# My div displays but only after I press a button for the second time

Tags: javascript, html, performance, runtime

I'm making a rock paper scissors game with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. 
The way my program works is that I'll press a button that reads either rock, paper, or scissors. After the button is pressed a function will run that will generate a random choice from a computer. Then the the user input will compare to the computer input. So, let's say that the user selects "rock" and computer selects "scissors", then a message will display saying "rock beats scissors." The problem is I can only get this message to run the second time i press the button.

Here's my code:

```
    // Make the variables
const userScore = 0;
const compScore = 0;


function showInstruct() {
            var show = document.getElementById('hideInstruct');
            if (show.style.display === "none") {
                show.style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                show.style.display = "none"
            }
        }

        function hideButtons() {
            document.getElementById('buttonDiv').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'flex';
            document.getElementById('nextRound').style.display = 'none';

            revealRps();

            setCountdown();
        }

        function setCountdown() {
            var numberS = 3;
            var x = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = numberS;
            numberS--;
            if (numberS < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "VS";
                document.getElementById('rps').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('nextRound').style.display = 'flex';
                document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'none';
                compare();
            }
            }, 950);
        }

        function revealRps() {
            document.getElementById('rps').style.display = 'flex';
            document.getElementById('nextRound').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function hideRps() {
            document.getElementById('rps').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'flex';
        }

        function compare() {
            var random = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
            var comp = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
            let compDraw = random[comp];

            rockBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log("Butts")
                if (compDraw == 'scissors') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('rockBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                    clearMessage();
                }
                else if (compDraw == 'paper')
                {
                    document.getElementById('paperBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                    clearMessage();
                }
                else if (compDraw == 'rock')
                {
                    document.getElementById('draw').style.display = 'flex';
                    clearMessage();
                }
            });
        }
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extreme Rock Paper Scissors!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0l">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Rocker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Rocker&family=Schoolbell&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Long+Cang&family=New+Rocker&family=Schoolbell&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RPS.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RPS.js"></script>

    <div class="titleWords">
        <h1>EXTREME ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!</h1>
    </div>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="beats">
        <div id="rockBeats">ROCK BEATS SCISSORS</div>
        <div id="paperBeats">PAPER BEATS ROCK</div>
        <div id="scissorsBeats">SCISSORS BEATS PAPER</div>
        <div id="draw">DRAW</div>
        <div id="noInput">YOU DIDN'T CLICK ANYTHING. COMPUTER AUTOMATICALLY WINS</div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonDiv">
        <button id="playButton" = onclick="hideButtons()">PLAY GAME</button>
        <button id="instructions" onclick="showInstruct()">INSTRUCTIONS<button>

    </div>


    <div id="hideInstruct">
        <p>The premise - This is war! And you must choose your attacks carefully.
        When you press PLAY GAME a countdown clock will countdown from 3. During that time you need to make a selection of how you're going to attack. Are you going to use Rock, Paper, or Scissors? 
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>The logistics - If you choose Rock and the computer chooses scissors, you crush those scissors into dust!  If you choose scissors and the computer chooses paper, you slice the paper into shreds! And if you choose paper and the computer chooses rock, you smear the rock with the a major paper-cut! However, if you choose Rock and the computer chooses Paper than you lose. In essense, the computer can do the same things to you that you can do to it. If you and the computer both draw the same thing, than it's considered a draw and nothing happens. And one more thing. If time runs out and you've selected nothing, than the computer automatically wins the point.</p>
        <br>
        <p>How to win - For each victory, that's one point. The first player to reach 3 points wins the game!</p>
    </div>

    <article id="countdown">
        <p id="number">3</p>
    </article>

    <footer id="rps">
        <button type="button" id="rockBtn" onclick="hideRps()">ROCK</button>
        <button type="button" id="paperBtn" onclick="hideRps()">PAPER</button>
        <button type="button" id="scissorsBtn" onclick="hideRps()">SCISSORS</button>
    </footer>

    <div id="input">
        <p id="locked">Your answer is locked in</p>
    </div>

    <div id="nextRound">
        <button id="nextButton" onclick="hideButtons()">Next Round</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **compare** function I think you have an issue which causes what is happening on your app now, try to check this line:

```
rockBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
```

rockBtn is not defined!!